# Difference between Logger.getLogger(className) and LogFactory.getLog(className )?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I know its a package difference

1) `org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz);`

2) `org.apache.commons.logging.Log log = LogFactory.getLog(clazz);`

The first one uses loggers via `log4j` and the second one uses `commons.logging`. We have a huge project where in some classes loggers are configured using `log4j` and in some cases its `commons.logging`.

I did find a log4j property file though.Is there a similar property file for `commons.logging` ? Where do I configure for commons-logging ?. I am unable to see the logs generated by `commons-logging`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Commons logging wraps other logging libraries; if you're using log4j it'll use that config file.

Comment: So commons-logging uses Log4j internally? Please explain what you mean. I have very little idea of this.

Comment: you can use commons-logging.properties file

Comment: How about you look at the commons logging docs? It wraps other logging libraries, not just log4j. You should, however, create all your logs in the same way.

Comment: @DaveNewton: So, if I have a log4j.jar in my classpath and log4j property file, will the common-logging automatically refer to log4j property ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, commons-logging is a facade API that was suppose to abstract you from underlying logging framework (in practice there was a choice between [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j) and `java.util.logging`) so that you could switch from one to another without touching the code - just by switching libraries available on the CLASSPATH.

Unfortunately due to some design mistakes it had issues with complex class-loading environments, like application servers. Currently it is effectively superseded by [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j).

In your case I would recommend sticking with one API - either Log4J or commons-logging, even though commons-logging will (most likely) delegate to log4J. You can also migrate to using SLF4J and install bridging APIs, but this is slightly more advanced.

Comment: I think you mean supersceded ... not suppressed.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: I can see the loggers configured via log4j, while those from commons-logging are not getting generated. Some configuration problem you think?

Comment: @StephenC Welllllll... it hasn't been suppressed *yet* ;)

Comment: @ShashankKadne: the two code snippets you provided are equivalent, both will use logger named as `clazz`. If you think this is some configuration issue (maybe commons-logging isn't using Log4J after all?) switch commons-logging logger with Log4J for a moment and see if it helps.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: ok. I will check and see.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I tried with Log4J and it worked. Don't know whats the problem with commons-logging. Thanks a lot for your help :)